# Conformal mapping in a region imply analiticity

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I've been reading Needham's book Visual Complex Analysis and stopped at the following theorem: a conformal mapping in a region implies analyticity. Could someone explain this theorem to me better geometrically? Furthermore, another consequence that I didn't understand is the fact that the function and its conjugate cannot be analytic at the same time.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave out some of the technical details here

Geometrically speaking, conformal maps are locally rotation-dilations. Conformal maps are supposed to preserve angles. To specify the angle of intersection of two intersecting lines, we are really looking at the angle of intersection of their tangents. The tangents of the curves at their point of intersection, and the tangents of the conformally transformed curves, should intersect at the same angle. In order to guarantee that the transformed curves have a tangent in the first place, the conformal map should be (real) differentiable. Now, the tangents of the transformed curve only depend on the constant and linear part of the conformal map. And then the angle only depends on the linear part, so on the differential of the map. The differential is a linear map, and the only way for a linear map to preserve angles is for it to be a rotation-dilation, meaning that it rotates and dilates, nothing else. The matrix representation of such a linear map is always of the form

$$r\begin{pmatrix}\cos\varphi&-\sin\varphi\\ \sin\varphi&\cos\varphi\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix},$$

Where $r>0$ or equivalently $a^2+b^2\neq0$. Such a map dilates by a factor of $r$ and rotates by the angle $\varphi$. But the second form of the matrix let's us see a different aspect: applying this map to a complex number thought of as a vector is the same as multiplying the number by $a+\mathrm ib$. So the conformal map's linear approximation can be expressed as multiplication by a complex number. But that's the same as being complex differentiable! So conformal maps are complex differentiable. And since this is true at every point, they are in fact holomorphic/analytic. (Another way to see this is that the matrix above contains the partial derivatives of the function, since it is the Jacobian, and then it's easy to verify that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied).

The corollary about the conjugate goes as follows: let $f$ be analytic and not constant on a connected domain. Then it is conformal on its domain except at the isolated points where it's derivative is $0$. So its conjugate is not conformal anywhere. But if the conjugate were analytic, then it would in fact be conformal except on a set of isolated points where its derivative vanishes (since it can't have zero derivative except at isolated points, otherwise it would be constant, and so $f$ would be constant, which it is not). So the conjugate can't be analytic.

The exception of course happens when $f$ is constant. Then its conjugate is also constant and thus analytic.

Comment: Thank you! Good explanation! But what was the point that Needham  tried to explain with the above image?Especially with the idea of a region.

Comment: I think that's just meant to illustrate that conformal maps preserve angles. The triangles are no longer triangles after the transformation, but the angles are still the same.

Comment: As for the thing about regions: I don't have the book, and I'm not 100% sure about the English terminology, but if I'm not mistaken, a region is an open connected set. If so, connectedness is generally important in complex analysis because certain local behaviors of a function lead to global behaviors. But only in parts of the domain which are connected to the part where the local behaviors happen...

Comment: ...The identity theorem is such a case (functions being identical locally means that they are identical globally). And in the proof of the theorem about analyticity of the conjugate, the identity theorem is used. That's probably why he's talking about regions.

Comment: I understand.The point Needham tries to make with the above image is that although the mapping is conformant nothing guarantees that the expansion is constant, but I didn't get it. The page for this discussion is 213.

Comment: My question then is, why preserving angles (conformal mapping) also implies that the expansion is constant. And on the other hand, why a constant expansion implies an angle preservation (in a neighborhood ).

Comment: He probably means constant in all directions, not at every point, right (I don't have the book, sadly)? Then it boils down to the question why angle preserving linear maps dilate the same way in every direction. Well, imagine a linear map dilated the horizontal direction twice as much as the vertical direction. Then the angle between the horizontal and any diagonal direction would change (you should try this yourself on a piece of paper).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128890/discussion-between-hilton-santana-and-vercassivelaunos).

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Could you please name any book explaining in more detail the proof of the fact ''angle-preserving maps are holomorfic/analytic''?

Comment: @Rainbow I'm sorry but I can't. I didn't learn complex analysis from a book, but from lectures.